# django remove source files and generate pyc files

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to remove all .py files in my django project.But pyc files are not generated as yet..

What is the settings that needs to be changed to generate the .pyc files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`compileall` can be used to compile all Python scripts in the project directory.

```
python -m compileall path/to/project
```

Comment: But my pyc files are  generated when httpd is restarted..ANy changes in httpd conf file to do this..

Comment: No they aren't; they're generated on module import.

Comment: So if any source changes for example project1/views.py should i just use the command python -m compileall path/to/project or restart httpd also? or both

Comment: How can you have source changes once you've removed all the source files?

Comment: I have compiled all python files in django project, __cache__ folder created, having compiled files in it. Now i want to remove source files, only pyc files should be there. But when i remove source file, it gives me ImportError, it should refer pyc file, but it is not refering them. How to solve this problem?