# How can we secure django python files for production release?

Tags: django, python-3.x

As we know python is interpreted language and we've to give it in the readable format?
But how we can secure those files for production release so the customer can't change it or modify it?
As like in Bin in `C++`, jar in `JAVA` and `.exe` in `.Net`

We've referred [Ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377177/django-production-deployment-should-we-not-remove-source-files) , [Ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311265/django-remove-source-files-and-generate-pyc-files) and [Ans3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828148/how-to-deploy-django-server-into-production-environment-without-a-full-source-co) but it doesn't work for us.

Comment: It seems to me Python is the wrong tool if this is a hard project requirement. Providing hosting to your clients and not giving them access to the server is how many commercial projects plan to serve products that can't be satisfactorily obfuscated; this has the advantage of turning your product into a subscription service (though that obviously comes with the overhead of necessarily providing ongoing technical support).

Answer (score 1):

I think picking other tools and even programming languages is the best bet for you.

Python and django serve a different purpose and even if you find a way to do what you want, still there won't be a community behind what you are doing and there will be no support so basically you're on your own or you have to build a community with the same goal yourself which might be a bad idea because the core community won't be a help just because you're working on a completely different goal.

But if you have to do it with python then i can think of one solution which is build an API and let others use it. If your clients can't find a way to use the API which needs some programming, then you can also build a client-side project which you can share with everyone without risking to expose your core project's code.

Good luck